# Google Calendar Feed

Tags: php, jquery, calendar

I am trying to add a Google calendar to a website I'm making that the client will be able to update themselves. I found this: http://mikeclaffey.com/google-calendar-into-html/ which has been quite helpful, but I am a bit stuck.

The website I am building is using PHP template and the page contents is contained within the $content variable. Here is the link I'm working on: http://victoriasawyer.com/AmosTheTransparent.

The calendar feed is the top one of the two lists of Tour Dates. I would like the top one to look similar to the bottom one. The same would be ideal but not necessary.

The biggest issue I'm having is with the start date and time. In the title of the event I would like just the date to show (preferably like 10/03/14) not the time. I have figured out how to display just the time separately without issue. Is there some way to change the date format?

The other issue I'm having is the order that the events are appearing. I would like the events to show with the soonest one first in the list and the furthest one last in the list. I added the additional parameters as instructed in the tutorial (orderby=starttime and sortorder=ascending) but they do not display correctly.

The url I am using is: https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/qmfadhgtq2kmabsi3dlb456v98%40group.calendar.google.com/public/full?orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true&alt=json. Is there something I can adjust or add to fix the order?

Any help will be much appreciated (even if you can recommend an alternative. It just needs to be customizable, and so far this seems to be the best option I have found).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP's [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) like this:

```
$date = new DateTime('Sun Nov 16 2014 00:30:00 GMT+0000');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

You can then use the predefined formats in PHP which are [listed here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format it into whatever style you like.

```
echo $date->format('d/m');
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: Do I have to know what dates are going to be used? or can I make it so that any date appears like that?

Comment: You can make it so any date gets formatted. You can just put the variable in like this `$date = new DateTime($startDate);`